# How to get order details by mail when paypal payments are on hold?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal Smart Buttons for a food online delivery/pickup solution, and expect PayPal to send the order detail (=list of ordered items) to the restaurant.

PayPal Sandbox does this in mails with subjects like "Zahlung erhalten von info@example.tld" (payment received from info@example.tld).

Problem: For the live system, PayPal instead sends mails with subjects like "€21,60 EUR von *Name* steht als vorgemerktes Guthaben zur Verfügung" (You received 21.60 EUR from *name* as reserved credit). These mails only say that PayPal keeps the money for 21 days - and the do not contain the list of ordered items - only the sender, date, amount, fee and transaction code.

[image: PayPal hold email]

What do I have to do that the receiving restaurant gets informed of what is ordered - without logging in into PayPal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are transactions that you are capturing via API, you can send an email at capture time.

If you are not capturing via API, you could [create a Webhook or IPN listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/).

Either way you need to send your own email once you have knowledge of the transaction. You can choose whether to send it in 100% of cases or only when the status is held. Probably best to send it in 100% of cases and have the receiving restaurant get used to this type of notification directly from you.